# Rotate a 2D contour plot through 360 degrees to create 3D plot (Python, Mayavi/Matplotlib)

Tags: python, visualization

I have three 1D arrays, which represent radius, height, and an intensity measured at that point. I have plotted these to create a 2D contour map. A simple example of the way in which the data is stored is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
y = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
intensity = [5,6,8,9,9,11,15,5,2]

plt.xlabel('Radius')
plt.ylabel('Height')

plt.tricontourf(x,y,intensity)
plt.colorbar(label='Intensity')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I've plotted this using Matplotlib as an example, but it's been suggested Mayavi might be better suited?

I want to create a 3D plot by 'sweeping' the 2D plot through 360 degrees, creating a disk which is azimuthally symmetric. See image below to explain the idea...

[image]

...with the data interpolated smoothly through the 360 degrees.

While there are no currently no questions that seem to duplicate this, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159942/how-do-you-radially-sweep-out-a-1d-array-to-plot-3d-figure-in-python-to-repr) is close to the kind of thing I need.

Answer (score 2):

I thought you want to create a lot of pairs of filled contour plots. In each pair, the two plots are symmetric about the `z` axis. Here I give a matlab script:

```
clc
close all
clear all

sign = [-1, 1];
x = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3];
z = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3];
intensity = [5, 6, 8, 9, 9, 11, 15, 5, 2];

for i = 1:2
    x_i = x .* sign(i);
    z_i = z;
    intensity_i = intensity;

    X_I = [1:0.2:3] .* sign(i);
    Z_I = [1:0.2:3];

    [X_T, Z_T] = meshgrid(X_I, Z_I);

    intensity_T = griddata(x_i, z_i, intensity, ...
        X_T, Z_T);

    Pnts = [X_T(:), zeros(size(X_T(:))), Z_T(:)];
    T = delaunay([X_T(:), Z_T(:)]);

    patch('Vertices', Pnts, ...
        'Faces', T, ...
        'FaceVertexCData', intensity_T(:), ...
        'FaceColor', 'interp', ...
        'EdgeAlpha', 0.0, ...
        'facealpha', 1); colorbar; hold on
end

plot3([0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 3], 'k-'); hold on
text(0, 0, 3.1, 'z axis'); hold on
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');
view(3)
```

The result is below:

[image]

I only show one pair here. In the above code, I set all the `y` coordinates to zero, and thus, only `x` and `z` are used. The `for-loop` means two plot, one is in `x < 0` and another is in `x > 0`. Then, I use `meshgrid` and `griddata`, which are kind of interpolation. Finally, I show the plot by `patch` command, with a triangulation created by `delaunay` as well as the `intensity` values on nodes.

I am not sure why the pair of plots looks like not symmetric. Maybe the reason is the `griddata` command.

***---UPDATE 1---***

Now, I understood your purpose: you have had some existing datasets on some planes and you wanted to interpolate more data on other planes.

Similarly, you can use `griddata` in matlab to do interpolation.

A matlab exmaple is below:

```
clc
close all
clear all

spacing_degree = 45;
range_degree = [0, 360 - spacing_degree];
NUM_plots = 360 / spacing_degree;

Pnt_3D = cell(NUM_plots, 1);
T_3D = cell(NUM_plots, 1);
Intensity_3D = cell(NUM_plots, 1);

Pnt_3D_existing = [];
Intensity_3D_existing = [];

for i = 0:spacing_degree:315

    [X Z] = meshgrid([0:0.5:2], [-1:0.5:1]);

    Pnts = [X(:), zeros(size(X(:))), Z(:)];

    if (i ~= 0)
        Pnts(:, :) = Quaternion_Rotation(i, 0, 0, 1, ...
            Pnts(:, 1), Pnts(:, 2), Pnts(:, 3));
    end

    T = delaunay(X(:), Z(:));

    Pnt_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1} = Pnts;
    T_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1} = T;

    % supposed that intensity values on xz and yz planes are known
    % I will generate some random data to represent these known data
    if (i == 0 || i == 90 || i == 180 || i == 270)

        if (i == 0 || i == 90)
            Intensity_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1} = ones(size(Pnts, 1), 1) .* ((i / spacing_degree + 1) .* 20) .* rand(size(Pnts, 1), 1);
        else
            % make symmetric data
            Intensity_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1} = Intensity_3D{(i - 180) / spacing_degree + 1};
        end

        Pnt_3D_existing = [Pnt_3D_existing; Pnts];
        Intensity_3D_existing = [Intensity_3D_existing;
                            Intensity_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}];

    else
        Intensity_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1} = ones(size(Pnts, 1), 1) .* -20;
    end

end

% now we finished generate existing data on xz and yz plane
% and, data on other planes are all -20!
figure(1)
title('Existing data')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z'); hold on

for i = 0:spacing_degree:315
    patch('Vertices', Pnt_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}, ...
        'Faces', T_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}, ...
        'FaceVertexCData', Intensity_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}, ...
        'FaceColor', 'interp', ...
        'EdgeAlpha', 0.2, ...
        'facealpha', 1); hold on;
end

view(3); colorbar

% now let us interpolate data on other planes

for i = [45, 135]

    if (i == 45 || i == 135)

        Intensity_TT = griddata(Pnt_3D_existing(:, 1), Pnt_3D_existing(:, 2), Pnt_3D_existing(:, 3), Intensity_3D_existing(:, 1), ...
            Pnt_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}(:, 1), Pnt_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}(:, 2), Pnt_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}(:, 3), 'nearest');

        Intensity_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1} = Intensity_TT;
        Intensity_3D{(i + 180) / spacing_degree + 1} = Intensity_TT;

        Pnt_3D_existing = [Pnt_3D_existing; Pnt_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}; Pnt_3D{(i + 180) / spacing_degree + 1}];
        Intensity_3D_existing = [Intensity_3D_existing;
                            Intensity_TT; Intensity_TT];

    end

end

figure(2)
title('Existing data and interpolating data')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z'); hold on

for i = 0:spacing_degree:315
    patch('Vertices', Pnt_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}, ...
        'Faces', T_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}, ...
        'FaceVertexCData', Intensity_3D{i / spacing_degree + 1}, ...
        'FaceColor', 'interp', ...
        'EdgeAlpha', 0.2, ...
        'facealpha', 1); hold on;
end

view(3); colorbar
```

In the above code, I generated random data on xz and yz plane to represent the existing dataset, and then interpolated more data on other planes. Note that the rotation function `Quaternion_Rotation` is a self-defined function. If the code is helpful, I can give you that function.

Results are below:
[image]

Unknown data are all -20! Then the interpolating result is below:

[image]

Hope that the results are what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. However, rather than create a 3D plot of many 2D panels, I am trying to interpolate around the 360 degrees, to end up with a kind of 3D 'donut' contour plot

Comment: I suppose that you have some datasets. In each dataset, the coordinates are coplanar, and also, with associating `intensity` value. Then, you want to interpolate more data on other planes which are also symmtric about the same axis?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The data is in the form I have given in the example (radius vs. height, with each point having an associated intensity value). I would like to create a 3D disk from this data which is azimuthally symmetric.

Comment: @lucas, what you are writing here is different from what is written in your question. So, you don't want to create multiple slices in your 3D dataset?

Comment: no, perhaps the illustration is unclear? I want to rotate the 2D contour plot fully around 360 degrees. But rather than take a 2D slice at each step, I want to interpolate around the 360 degrees to form a 3D disk

Comment: @lucas Please see the edited answer and if it is what you want.